# older hp laptop with ubuntu on it won't connect to the internet?

Tags: wireless, internet, intel-wireless

i recently put ubuntu on my older laptop and this is the first time i've really used linux. It will let me connect to internet if i use ethernet but not wirelessly. How can i fix this?

Comment: Open terminal Ctrl+Alt+t , run `sudo lshw -C network` , add outputs to the question.

Answer (score 0):

- Connect to Ethernet
- Open **Additional Drivers** (you may find it as a separate program or as a tab in update manager depending on your version)
- you should be able to see your ireless card listed; click **Activate**

Comment: i dont have ethernet where i am now is there anyway to get this without it?
(at a hotel asking this off of my girlfriend's mac)

Comment: You will need an Internet connection to download required drivers and install them (check Additional drivers anyway and try to click activate - maybe it got downloaded already and just need to be activated -which I doupt actually :)

Comment: Additional Drivers is helpful for Broadcom devices. Is that what he has?